# Reverse geolocation synchronization in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, semaphore

I need to convert my latitude and longitude, received from the server to location. As I user Parse API I don't find that's a good idea to convert them in `viewDidLoad`, so I decided to make it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I tried this approach: [Synchronization of concurrent processes execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897731/synchronization-of-concurrent-processes-execution)

Here:

```
...

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:meeting.location.latitude
                                                                  longitude:meeting.location.longitude] completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
     meeting.location.displayName =  [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
     NSLog(@"%@", meeting.location.displayName);
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
 }];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

cell.subInfo.text = meeting.location.displayName;

return cell;
```

But it seems to hang endlessly. Where am I wrong?

*UPD:* I've tried to move all this stuff back to `viewDidLoad`. In my for loop, where I parse downloaded from Parse.com information I now have:

```
... 
_location.latitude = ((PFGeoPoint *)entry[@"location"]).latitude;
_location.longitude = ((PFGeoPoint *)entry[@"location"]).longitude;

_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[self reverseGeocode:_location];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
...
```

Where `_semaphore` is `@property (strong) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;`

`reverseGeocode:`:

```
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: [[CLLocation alloc]       initWithLatitude:meetingLocation.latitude
                                                                  longitude:meetingLocation.longitude] completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
     meetingLocation.displayName =  [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);
 }];
```

Now it seems to *hang*, but I have no idea where, because it doesn't even enter the geocoded completionHandler block.

Comment: What does your `NSLog(@"%@", meeting.location.displayName);` show?

Comment: @CharlesA nothing, it seems that program never enters this block. I'll update my post in a moment

Answer (score 0):

You tried to get the value for meeting.location.displayName in the block, and then set cell.subInfo.text with the value of meeting.location.displayName after the block. The problem will be the line `cell.subInfo.text = meeting.location.displayName;` can be executed before the block is returned. You can try to put the line `cell.subInfo.text = meeting.location.displayName;` inside the block.

But I don't see why you want to reverse geolocation in this method, the reverse function may be called every time when the user scroll to particular if you don't set the condition when to do reversion. If viewDidLoad is not a good idea for your design, try viewWillAppear.

Comment: I've updated my post with your recommendations, but no result

Comment: try to remove the line `dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);` inside the block, although I don't see why it's needed there.